# Django: Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/index/'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: GET '/index/'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, redirect, url-pattern

I am getting the above error when i tried to redirect from my UserAuth app to UserArea app.
It says 'NoReverseMatch at /index/'.

**UserAuth/views.py**

```
def loginUser(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            # return render(request, 'home.html')
            return redirect('nsUserArea:urlUserHome')
            
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'User name or password is incorrect')

    return render(request, "Login.html")
```

**USerAuth/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.loginUser, name="urllogin"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="urllogout"),
    path('register/', views.register, name="urlregister"),
    path('home/', views.home, name="urlhome"),
    
]
```

**UserArea/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexPage, name="urlUserHome"),
]
```

My main project urls.py file is this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('UserAuth.urls', namespace="nsUserAuth")),
    path('index/', include('UserArea.urls', namespace="nsUserArea")),
]
```

**UserArea/views.py**

```
def IndexPage(request):
    return redirect(request, 'home.html')
```

**home.html**

```
<h1>Home</h1>
```

Comment: Show the view `IndexPage` and it's template.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat updated in question

Comment: `return redirect(request, 'home.html')` did you mean to write `return render(request, 'home.html')` instead? `redirect` is used to redirect a user somewhere else, `render` is used to render a template.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same problem that you are getting:

[image: screenshot]

I modified my `redirect` to `render`.
Change

```
return redirect()
```

to

```
return render()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def IndexPage(request):
    return redirect(request, 'home.html')
```

Try without request

```
def IndexPage(request):
    return redirect('home.html')
```